# Throw error on type instability

Tags: julia

When I write code in julia I tend to declare the type of every variable I use. But every now and then I forget an odd one. More importantly, sometimes the compiler cannot detect the type because of suboptimal code.This means that I have to check manually for type instabilities.

This got me wondering. Can I tell the compiler to just throw an error if there is a variable with unstable type?

Comment: Not exacly what you are asking for, but check out Traceur.jl: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/ann-traceur-jl-make-your-julia-code-not-totally-slow/9469

Comment: Also `@inferred` macro from `Test` is a partial solution (it will catch return type instability).

Comment: Declaring less types might be the way to go, as it allows a single function to be compiled for more type signatures. The Julian way is to use the most general types which preserve the shape/meaning of the function (for example, types which specify scalars vs arrays). But then, to each his style, and others may have different opinions.